# Upload file without using move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, ajax

Can I upload a file without using move_uploaded_file?

My steps:

- Upload file using usual form "file", then store the full path of temp file `/tmp/phpwcL9F3`.
- Do an AJAX call to `copy()` that    temp file to my upload
  folder.

Could I do that?

**Update:**
The logic flow I want to implement (actually it's from my customer):

- Choose file, press "Submit" => Processing. A dialog is shown while the process is running. => AJAX file uploading.
- If file existed. Show dialog OK, Cancel. If press Cancel, nothing uploaded. **If press OK, it actually uploads the file**.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Is the upload folder in a different physical location than /tmp?

Comment: I think there is a logic problem, you said **if file existed and canceled** this means you **have** to upload the file anyway to check if the md5 checksum is the same. So why bother and move the uploaded file with a "custom" function while there already exists `move_uploaded_file()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this question:

1. Actually upload that file to a temporary location.
2. When confirming it (pressing OK), move the file to the expected
   place.
3. Finally remove the temporary file.

After step 1, the file really exists so it has a name and a path so we can check its existence.

Answer (score 0):

You should also take a look at `file_get_content` php function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com/) This uploads the files in a directory you specify using chunking.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i have a separate php function that will check if the file is existing or not (ex. fileExisting()).
It will be called by ajax when the user clicks on the Upload button (file name will be sent also). When fileExisting() returns true, 
it will prompt the user if he/she wants to overwrite the file.

If the user selected OK, it will now actually submit the form.

Comment: How could you get the file in the first step? Is it file uploading using "file" form?

Comment: in which step? during the actual uploading of file? or during checking if file is existing or not?

Comment: Before checking fileExisting, if you don't use a form "file", how to get the file?

Comment: I'm just passing the filename to the php function fileExisting() which is called by ajax. I'm not yet submitting the form at that point.

Comment: You can't get the full path of uploaded file (for checking existing()) if you don't use FILE upload protocol.

Comment: I set a fixed destination directory. And every time I upload file, I rename the temp file to its original name so I can check if it is existing